# Hacking WebSocket. Docker Exec vs Docker Attach (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, docker

I'm using `docker attach using a websocket` so I can connect it to a terminal (xtermjs)

The problem is that when I attach I cannot use any commands because my container is running a script with a while(true) loop. (I use docker command ./script.sh)

The obvious answer is to use Docker exec that works! The problem is that I have no idea how I can connect it to my terminal since there's no docker exec using websocket.

**Is there a way to hack this to use docker exec or a way to attach to the container and send somehow the script to background?**

My current approach

Java

```
   public String execConsole(String containerName) {
    Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
    Container container = getContainer(containerName);
    //attach
    return "ws://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort() + "/containers/" + container.getId() + "/attach/ws?logs=1&stdin=1&stderr=1&stdout=1&stream=1";
}
```

javascript

```
 $('#btnConnect').click(function () {
    $('#btnConnect').html('<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> Connecting');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/connect-console',
        type: 'post',
        data: {containerName: containerName},
        success: function (url) {
            $('#connectDiv').hide();
            $('#terminalDiv').show();

            term = new Terminal({
                screenKeys: true,
                useStyle: true,
                cursorBlink: true
            });
            ws = new WebSocket(url,true);
            ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
            term.on('data', function (data) {
                ws.send(data);
            });
            term.open(document.getElementById("terminal"), true);
            ws.onopen = function() {
                console.log('ws connected');
            };
            ws.onerror = function() {
                console.log('ws error');
            };
            ws.onclose = function() {
                console.log('ws closed');
            };
            ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
                var data = decoder.decode(evt.data);
                term.write(data);
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: no. it works. but this is attach. I want exec

Comment: Might help this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.31/#tag/Exec